# Integral involving the Associated Laguerre polynomials

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

I'm trying to solve this integral

$\int_{0}^{\infty} L^n_p L^n_{p'} e^{-x} x^{n-1} dx = \dfrac{1}{n} \dfrac{(p!)^3}{(p-n)!} \delta_{pp'}$

I started with integration by parts where

$u = $ $L^n_p L^n_{p'} e^{-x}$

$dv = x^{n-1} $

After some simplifications, I got the following:$\\$

$ I = \frac{-1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} L^n_p L^n_{p'} e^{-x} x^{n} dx + \frac{-1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx}  L^n_{p'} L^n_p e^{-x} x^{n} dx + \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} L^n_p L^n_{p'} e^{-x} x^{n} dx$

The integral

$\frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} L^n_p L^n_{p'} e^{-x} x^{n} dx$

is already known, which is equal to

$\dfrac{(p!)^3}{(p-n)!} \delta_{pp'}$

after multiply it with $\frac{1}{n}$ it becomes

$\dfrac{1}{n} \dfrac{(p!)^3}{(p-n)!} \delta_{pp'} $

All of that was okay, the issue here is with the rest integrals

$\frac{-1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} L^n_p L^n_{p'} e^{-x} x^{n} dx + \frac{-1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx}  L^n_{p'} L^n_p e^{-x} x^{n} dx $

I assumed that $p = p'$ so that this integral can be solved, so it becomes:

$\frac{-2}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} L^n_p L^n_{p} e^{-x} x^{n} dx $

This integral must be equal to zero, so that the final result is $\dfrac{1}{n} \dfrac{(p!)^3}{(p-n)!} \delta_{pp'} $

But I'm not sure with respect to what should I integrate? It's obvious not with respect to p nor n, there's some other substitution, but I have no idea what should that be.

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty } L_p^n(x) L_r^n(x) \exp (-x) x^{n-1} \, dx=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\Gamma (n+p+1)}{n p!} & p\leq r \\
 \frac{\Gamma (n+r+1)}{n r!} & p>r \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ for: `n > 0, p >= 0, r >= 0` and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$,$p\in \mathbb{Z}$,$r\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: From where did that assumption comes?

Comment: My solution(CAS me helped to solve) is true only with this assumption what to write in the comment above.

Comment: Well yeah, I know it's true only with this assumption. 
But what I'm trying to say is what steps were taken to get this conclusion?
I didn't understand where did these conditions come from.
Kindly, I need more explanation.

Comment: No steps was taken,I'm only putt random values to my solution and on the basis of this I have drawn conclusions.